# Xcode 7.1.1 UINavigationBar does not cover the entire width of the screen with iPhone 6 and above

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

My app was acting fine till I updated my Xcode. For some odd reason, my UINavigationBar is no longer covering the entire width of the screen for devices iPhone6 and above.

For iPhone 5:

[image]

For iPhone 6 and above:

[image]

Comment: can you tell me your navigation is drag and drop Or Create Programetically in Appdelegate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't used autolayout. Okay no problem..

Follow below steps:
1. you need to keep it empty on Launch Screen file.
2. Create Launch image source and then add iPhone 6 and 6+ splash screens

Then it will work your navigation bar automatically fit based on device.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer.  I did use auto layout. I embedded the UInavigationController in my UIViewController in storyboard.